# How to update 3rd party Android application without user action?

Tags: android

I would like to know if it's possible to update a third party application without user action.

By 3rd party, I mean an application not located on the Android Market but rather on a specific website.

Thx

John

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible or how it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

I noted that the android market can self-update the installed apps. The user is not asked about an acknowledgment.

I don't want to offer my self-coded app in the market. I found a way to update this app from my homepage, but the user must this affirm.

How it is possible to update an app without user action?